# Is Mastodon remove-orphans safe when multiple instances sharing an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails

I have two Mastodon v4.2.0 instances, a staging server and a live/production instance. They share an AWS S3 bucket for file storage. Both are hosted on DigitalOcean.

Is the command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/tootctl media remove-orphans` safe to run with this configuration? My concern is that running the command from the staging server will delete files needed by the live server.

The [documentation for this command](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/admin/tootctl/#media-remove-orphans) says:

> Scans for files that do not belong to existing media attachments, and remove them. Please mind that some storage providers charge for the necessary API requests to list objects. Also, this operation requires iterating over every single file individually, so it will be slow.

From this I gather that the command deletes files that aren't accounted for in Mastodon's database. The problem I fear is that files accounted for by one instance's database will look like orphans to the other instance.

Am I right to fear that the `remove-orphans` command is not safe on an S3 bucket shared by two instances?

Comment: What is the business related question or issue in here? As also what business environment are affecting the Problem?

Comment: The business question is: will I be messing up my server if I do this?

Comment: It's crucial to create a backup and snapshot of your data and test it thoroughly. It's not advisable to use the same resource for both testing and production environments. However, we cannot guarantee how your instances will handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: no, this command is not necessarily safe to run. Specifically, if you have any files in the S3 bucket (or other storage medium) that don't belong to your Mastodon database, then the command is unsafe.

Further, the command is unsafe if you have *more than one* Mastodon database pointing to the same S3 bucket. In my case, I have a production and a staging instance pointing to the same bucket. Because neither instance knows the other instance's files, `media remove-orphans` is not safe to run on either one.

I accidentally ran this command for a short time before noticing that something was wrong. I used `bin/tootctl accounts refresh --all` to restore files from remote servers that I had deleted locally.

Comment: remember that you need to accept your answer please. else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem ;/

Comment: Ha, thank you for the reminder and perhaps for the upvote